# Issues reading unread mails in Outlook

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto

I am trying to develop an add-in for Outlook. In that I want remove attachment when a new mail is received.

So I call my function on the `NewMailEx` event. It is working fine. In that function I try to find unread mails in the Outlook inbox. From those I remove the attachments.

My problem is: when I open Outlook, the first mail I received is not showing in the inbox (not in outlook c# code), so I can't remove the attachment from that mail.

From the second mail (after the first mail), I can get the received mail, so I can remove the attachments.

Whenever I close and reopen Outlook, the first mail I receive gives this problem.

At the first mail received there is no unread mail.

```
private void Application_NewMailEx(object Item)
{
    string senderEmailid = string.Empty;
    outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    Outlook.Attachments attachments;
    int test = myInbox.Items.Count;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipients recipients = ((Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[test]).Recipients;
    Outlook.Items unreadItems = myInbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true");
    if (unreadItems.Count > 0)
    {       
        foreach (Outlook.MailItem mail in unreadItems)
        {
            Outlook.Recipient recip;
            Outlook.ExchangeUser exUser;
            string sAddress;

            if (mail.SenderEmailType.ToLower() == "ex")
            {
                recip = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").CreateRecipient(mail.SenderEmailAddress);
                exUser = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
                sAddress = exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
            }
            else
            {
                sAddress = mail.SenderEmailAddress.Replace("'", "");
            }
            string[] emailAddressPart = sAddress.Split('@');
            string strSenderDomain = emailAddressPart[1];
            if (lstDomain.Any(item => item.Contains(strSenderDomain)))
            {
                attachments = mail.Attachments;
                int nAttachmentCount = mail.Attachments.Count;
                if (nAttachmentCount > 0)
                {
                    int j = nAttachmentCount;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= nAttachmentCount; i++)
                    {
                        mail.Attachments[j].Delete();
                        j--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class is not the best place for searching unread emails. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem, MeetingItem, or SharingItem. The EntryIDsCollection string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. The alternative way is to handle the ItemAdd event of the Items class.

Instead, you can wait until Outlook finishes synchronizing items and run your code for searching unread emails. The [SyncEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff866270.aspx) event of the SyncObject class is fired immediately after Microsoft Outlook finishes synchronizing a user’s folders using the specified Send/Receive group.

Also you may consider handling the  Startup or  MAPILogonComplete events. But they are fired before the synchronization is completed. Consider using a timer to run the procedure a bit after Outlook is started.

You can read about possible ways of handling incoming emails in the following series of articles:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)

Also I'd recommend breaking the chain of calls and delaclaring each property or method call on a separate line of code. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. This is particularly important if your add-in attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server. If you do not release these objects in a timely manner, you can reach the limit imposed by Exchange on the maximum number of items opened at any one time. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN.

Comment: pls give me a code to use syncend .....in c#.......  the above link  give only the vb code....pls help.....

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do about that. From the documentation on [`NewMailEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171304%28v=office.11%29.aspx):

> Also, the event will fire only if Outlook is running. In other words, it will not fire for the new items that are received in the Inbox when Outlook was not open.

That means you have to manually call your method to walk down all the unread emails when opening Outlook.

Comment: thank u sir......after ouening outlook......i send a mail to my outlook(outlook is open and till no new first mail received)....the attachment in the first mail was not removed...(but the function was executed....the problem is the count of unreaded mail was 0) .....pls help.....

Comment: You mean: the event isn't raised? How did you subscribe? What happens if you attach the debugger?

Comment: yes event is raised ......but due to unreaded mail count was 0.....it attachment donot get  deleted.....

Comment: Why do you want to find those items yourself? Why not rely on the list given you though the event? See the documentation in my post.

Comment: There is a code sample in the documentation referenced: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171304%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76974/discussion-between-rsb-and-patrick-hofman).